# Consuming a list of custom classes from a web service?

Tags: c#

I have a list of a class I made called MonitoringItem.

```
public class MonitoringItem
    {
        public int URLID { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public List<String> RequestHeaders { get; set; }
        public string RegexMatchString { get; set; }
        public string CheckType { get; set; }
        public string ExpectedResponseCode {get; set;}
    }
```

When I try to consume this on the client side, using a service reference I get:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebMonitor.GetURLsToMonitor.MonitoringItem[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebMonitor.GetURLsToMonitor.MonitoringItem>'  \\home\d\Source\Projects\WebMonitor\WebMonitor\WebMonitorProgram.cs 44  17  WebMonitor
```

This is my client code:

```
List<GetURLsToMonitor.MonitoringItem> m = new List<GetURLsToMonitor.MonitoringItem>();

GetURLsToMonitor.ws_GetURLsToMonitorSoapClient g = new GetURLsToMonitor.ws_GetURLsToMonitorSoapClient();
 m = g.GetURLsToMonitor(); <--This is where it is giving me the error
```

.

I'm not returning an array so not sure why it's saying this.

Comment: Also, my web service wraps the class in a list here:

public List<MonitoringItem> GetURLsToMonitor()

Comment: Change the properties of your service reference to materialize collections as lists instead of arrays.  You might even need to remove and re-add the reference with the proper settings.

Comment: Arrrgh that was it. Not sure how I missed that. Thank you!!!